# Spring and Rest Services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Working on a Rest tutorial threw the spring boot site and recieving a 404 error. The site says if I use to RestController annotation that a view(thyme leaf) is not required yet it seems I have this 404 error. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ronone.entity")
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private static final String template = "Hello %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World")String name){
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Plain ole java:

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL gives you a `404`?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/greeting

Comment: Is there any error logs in console when you start the spring boot application? Just to confirm that the application is launched correctly.

Comment: no noticeable errors in the print trace, app seems to start up correctly

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the latest compiled version for testing? I managed to put a quick test project using your classes on spring boot 1.5.2 and it ran fine.

Comment: Is the package of RestController comes under com.ronone.entity?

Answer (score 0):

Keep attention to `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Classes outside of base package will not be reachable.

It seems that `com.ronone.entity` is not the top level package, while `com.ronoe` is.

Thus, your controller is not loaded and page gives 404.

Answer (score 0):

The `@ComponentScan` searching for your project name, 
if you using gradle then the full project name should be in `settings.gradle`,
otherwise you can just remove the `@ComponentScan` annotation and the project will work fine,
or just put the right name of the project.

> Read more about `@ComponentScan` in the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)